# android download manager download file once

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, download-manager

I have below codes that when button clicked start download file, but the problem is when i click button  multiple times it keep downloading the same file multiple times.How can i prevent that? which code should i add and  where ?

```
    Button download= (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String path="http://xxxx.com/sound/ok.mp3";
            file_download(path);
        }
    });
                 }
     public void file_download(String uRl) {
     File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/yebo");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs();
    }

    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("pic")
            .setDescription("Downloading,Please Wait ...")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/yebo", "mimi.mp3");
             mgr.enqueue(request);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code.

```
      public void onClick(View view) {

                        String path="http://xxxx.com/sound/ok.mp3";
                        file_download(path);
download.setEnable(false);

                    }
```

if you do not want to disable your button then u can set a flag like:

```
int flag = 0;
 public void onClick(View view) {
if(flag == 0)
{                String path="http://xxxx.com/sound/ok.mp3";
                file_download(path);
flag += 1;
}


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `Button` and re-enable it after you are done e.g.

```
 final Button download= (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
      download.setEnabled(false);
      download.setAlpha(.2f); // grey it out
      String path="http://xxxx.com/sound/ok.mp3";
      file_download(path);
 }
```

Comment: @f2k No problem. Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you.